# MySQL erro 2002 conexão recusada

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu hospedei um site na [007gb.com](http://www.007gb.com) e estou tentado acessar meu banco de dado remoto mas recebo a mensagem

```
"Mensagem do erro: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Code: 2002
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on string in /srv/disk13/2292110/www/pirataswe0.medianewsonline.com/test.php on line 14"
```

O que pode ser?
eu criei um script em php para facilitar:

```
<?php

function connectdb() {
    try {
        $return = new PDO("mysql:host=179.213.XX.XX;port=3306,dbname=pwdb;charset=utf8", 'root', '***********',[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
      echo  $return = 'Mensagem do erro: ' . $exc->getMessage().
         '<br>Code: ' . $exc->getCode();
    }
    return $return;
}

$db = connectdb();
$select = $db->prepare("SELECT title FROM posts");
$select->execute();
echo $select->rowCount().'</br>';
while ($data = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $data['title'].'</br>';
}
```

A porta é a padrão mesmo, e ela está aberta no gateway que aponta para o ip e porta local.

Answer (score -3):

Para solucionar esse problema, basta seguir os seguintes passos. Antes de mais nada vamos instalar o banco de dados no MySQL:

```
# mysql_install_db
```

Em seguida é preciso gerar o sock:

```
# chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Agora vamos dar o start no servidor MySQL:

```
# safe_mysqld &
```

Beleza, o seu MySQL já esta rodando!

Abra outra janela de terminal e digite:

```
# mysql
```

Espero ter ajudado!